# automate telnet session python

Tags: python, telnet

I have setup with almost 80 Servers with custom OS which can only be installed by PXE. These server can only be accessed by telnet. I need guideline to automate telnet session to these and doing some complex task like changing bios settings and pressing CTRl+ALT+Del and doing hardware and raid status check from Bios utilities. All these things over telnet TUI(text user interface).

pytelnet lib don't seems to handle that much text and stucks most of times

DO let me know any possible solution or library available out there

Comment: Does it have to be in python? Have you looked into the `expect` command line utility? Automated interaction with terminals, prompts, etc is exactly what it was built for.

Comment: looks like there are several `expect`-like libraries for python such as `pcl-expect`, `pexpect-u`, `pexpect-serial`, `pexpect`, and `streamexpect`. Disclaimer: I haven't used any of these, just found them with `pip search expect`.

Comment: well does ? expect allows me do things like verifying raid status and changing Bios settings and pressing F10 also i need to if there is any solution or library out there to make this process little bit easier.
Currently with pexpect i am having issue with going throgh PXE menu.

Comment: expect doesn't "verify raid status" or "change bios settings". It just make it easier to write scripts against an interactive, text-based programs and sending text/data/control-characters over telnet and the like. If you can tell expect what prompts to expect and how to respond then it can do what you want. If that's not how the programs you want to interact with behave, then I guess expect won't help you.

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to interact with a full-screen terminal application, (the kinds of thing written with the curses library). Some googling for \[automate interact curses interface\] lead me to this, which seems applicable: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/m_YEbavLXow

Comment: looking into, thanks for hint